# Pipelining listing and copying files

Tags: terminal, pipeline, ls, cp

I have a server which is hosting my files which I can list with the following command:

```
xrdfs servername ls path/to/file
```

Similarly, I can copy file using the following command:

```
xrdcp server/path/to/file .
```

For, some reason the server doesn't support copying an entire folder(of course with -r option). So, I am trying to pipeline these two commands such a way that xrdfs will list the files and xrdcp will copy it to my destination. I tried the following line:

```
xrdfs servername ls path/to/file | xrdcp server/$() .
```

I get the following message:

```
Prepare: [ERROR] Invalid arguments
```

This is not very enlightening. Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer and I am posting here for reference

```
xrdfs servername ls path/to/file | while read -r out; do xrdcp server$out .; done
```